# How can I sort through the Graph query users who do not have a Manager?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graph, azure-active-directory, spfx

I tried to get users who have **manager** in my organization.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager&$select=id,userPrincipalName
```

But I get all users, those with managers and those without managers.

[image]
In the response I need only users who have **manager**.
How can I filter them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran the same query as you, I too got **same results** with users having manager and without manager like below:

```html
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager&$select=id,userPrincipalName
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, there is **no direct** graph query to retrieve only users
> having manager.  Instead, you can use any coding language to
> **customize** the response of above query.

In my case, I used below Python code and got only users having **manager** in the response like below:

```py
import requests

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager&$select=id,userPrincipalName"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

users_with_manager = [user for user in data["value"] if user.get("manager")]

for user in users_with_manager:
    print("User ID:", user["id"])
    print("User Principal Name:", user["userPrincipalName"])
```

**Response:**

[image]